# Create a variable with sparse index in pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo

I need help to create a variable with sparse indices.
I have something like this:

```
model.K = Set()
model.P = Set()
model.KP = Param(model.K, model.P, default=0)
```

I will load a CSV file for `model.KP` with value `KP==1` for the combinations of K & P.

```
model.X = Var(model.K, model.P)
```

I want to create this variable only for the combinations of K and P in the model.KP because when I create the variable with all the combinations of K and P, it is producing 37 million indices with the sets I give and this is creating memory issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a `Set` containing tuples `(k,p)` and use it as the set that defines both your variable and your parameter.

Define your set elements:

```
kp = []
for k in model.K:
    for p in model.P:
        foo_tuple = (k, p)
        kp.append(foo_tuple)
```

Note: Since you will use a CSV file to load your data, populationg `kp` with all K and P combinations can also be done at this time.

Then create a `Set` using elements in `kp`:

```
model.S = Set(initialize=kp)
```

I recommend not using default values in your `model.KP` parameter if you don't need it. Doing so will notify you of a missing value for an element where it should have one. But let's say that you still want to have all values of parameter `model.PK` to be `0` when no value was provided for tuple `(p,k)` and continue using default values, you should define your parameter like so:

```
model.KP = Param(model.S, default=0)
```

Then, defining your variable will be:

```
model.X = Var(model.S)
```

Comment: thanks Brunelle. I created a set with the tuples of K,P combinations and defined the set in pyomo with dimen=2. that solved everything.