# Sparse index use for optimization with Pyomo model

Tags: django, optimization, pyomo

I have a Pyomo model connected to a Django-created website.
My decision variable has 4 indices and I have a huge amount of constraints running on it.

Since Pyomo takes a ton of time to read in the constraints with so many variables, I want to sparse out the index set to only contain variables that actually could be 1 (i have some conditions on that)

I saw this post 
[Create a variable with sparse index in pyomo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54926298/create-a-variable-with-sparse-index-in-pyomo)

and tried a for loop for all my conditions. I created a set "AllowedVariables" to later put this inside my constraints.
But Django's server takes so long to create this set while performing the system check, it never comes out.

Currently i have this model:

```py
model = AbstractModel()
model.x = Var(model.K, model.L, model.F, model.Z, domain=Boolean)

def ObjRule(model):
    # some rule, sense maximize

model.Obj = pyomo.environ.Objective(rule=ObjRule, sense=maximize)

def ARule(model,l):
    maxA = sum(model.x[k,l,f,z] * for k in model.K for f in model.F 
               for z in model.Z and (k,l,f,z) in model.AllowedVariables)
    return maxA <= 1
model.maxA = Constraint(model.L, rule=ARule)
```

The constraint is exemplary, I have 15 more similar ones. I currently create "AllowedVariables" this way:

```py
AllowedVariables = []
for k in model.K:
    for l in model.L:
         ..... check all sorts of conditions, break if not valid
         AllowedVaraibles.append((k,l,f,z))

model.AllowedVariables = Set(initialize=AllowedVariables)
```

Using this, the Django server starts checking....and never stops

```py
performing system checks...
```

Sadly, I somehow need some restriction on the variables or else the reading for the solver will take way to long since the constraints contain so many unnecessary variables that have to be 0 anyways.

Any ideas on how I can sparse my variable set?

Comment: What do you think is the line that cause problem? Is the for loop never ending or is it `model.AllowedVariables = Set(initialize=AllowedVariables)`?

Comment: I mean, `performing system checks...` is vague. If you put prints or logs in your code, what is the last thing that was run before crashing? I don't see anything that should be hanging except on django's side and with your `..... check all sorts of conditions, break if not valid` part. It can even be something else, outside the code, like an error while building the model. More infos on what is hanging could be helpful. Cheers.

Comment: And I don't know the reason why you use a `break` statement in your loop. Maybe you are omitting to add important elements after the break? I personnaly prefer `if` statements when I want every elements to be checked.

Comment: The code is not crashing, its correct. Whenever i start Djangos local testserver, it will perfom system checks and pass all models down to the local server, while doing this, console is showing the line "performing system checks..." 
When i remove the whole loop creating the AllowedVariables, the system check with Django only takes seconds, so i know the reason is that it has to compute all those thousands of varaibles..

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you have any mean of knowing if the loop finished in Django? I know that building constraints can be also long when a lot a variables are involved. I see something that can slow down your model creation in your constraints rules. If the loop succeeds to end, it might be a good culprit. And leaving the `AllowedVariables` empty will only make empty sums in constraints, which are fast to generate.