# How to conditionally add variables to a Pyomo constraint based on predetermined data settings

Tags: pyomo

I'm new to Pyomo.

I would like to know if there is an elegant way to code a constraint that contains variables that we may or may not want to include.  The option to include them will be known at the time the model is solved and will be based on settings it reads in from the database.

A good example might be having slacks in the constraint, sometimes we want them and sometimes we don't.

I have tapped out a small demo below for a warehouse location example.  In equation *buildLimit* I have added a slack to allow the number of warehouses to exceed the build limit [the code might contain some syntax errors I haven't run it]

```
# Import pyomo
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverStatus, TerminationCondition

N = ['Harlingen', 'Memphis', 'Ashland']
M = ['NYC', 'LA', 'Chicago', 'Houston']

d = {('Harlingen', 'NYC'): 1956, \
     ('Harlingen', 'LA'): 1606, \
     ('Harlingen', 'Chicago'): 1410, \
     ('Harlingen', 'Houston'): 330, \
     ('Memphis', 'NYC'): 1096, \
     ('Memphis', 'LA'): 1792, \
     ('Memphis', 'Chicago'): 531, \
     ('Memphis', 'Houston'): 567, \
     ('Ashland', 'NYC'): 485, \
     ('Ashland', 'LA'): 2322, \
     ('Ashland', 'Chicago'): 324, \
     ('Ashland', 'Houston'): 1236 }

P = 2

model = ConcreteModel("warehouse location problem")

model.N = Set(dimen=1, initialize=N)
model.M = Set(dimen=1, initialize=M)
model.d = Param(model.N, model.M, within=PositiveIntegers, initialize=d)
model.P = Param(initialize=P)
model.y = Var(model.N, within=Binary)
model.x = Var(model.N, model.M, bounds=(0,1))
##########################
model.buildLimitSlack = Var(within=NonNegativeIntegers)
model.useSlacks = Param() # assume some data read will populate this at some stage before the solve
##########################

# Objective, minimise delivery costs
def obj_rule(model):
    return sum(model.d[n,m] * model.x[n,m] for n in model.N for m in model.M) + 99*model.buildLimitSlack
model.obj = Objective(rule=obj_rule)
# All customer demand must be met
def demand_rule(model, m):
    return sum(model.x[n,m] for n in model.N) == 1
model.demand = Constraint(model.M, rule=demand_rule)
# Can only ship from a warehouse if that warehouse is built
def supplyOnlyIfBuilt_rule(model, m, n):
    return model.x[n,m] <= model.y[n]
model.supplyOnlyIfBuilt = Constraint(model.M, model.N, rule=supplyOnlyIfBuilt_rule)
##############################
#### WE WANT THE SLACK IN THIS EQUATION TO BE OPTIONAL BASED ON DATA SETTINGS
def buildLimit_rule(model):
    return sum(model.y[n] for n in model.N) <= model.P + model.buildLimitSlack
model.buildLimit = Constraint(rule=buildLimit_rule)
##############################
```

I imagine we could have an if statement in the constraint, something like the following.  But we don't want that as our model equations will likely have **many** such optional variables in the same constraint and I don't want to have tons of nested if statements [unless there is a nice way to do this?].

```
def buildLimit_rule(model):
  if model.useSlacks:    
    return sum(model.y[n] for n in model.N) <= model.P + model.buildLimitSlack
  else:
    return sum(model.y[n] for n in model.N) <= model.P
model.buildLimit = Constraint(rule=buildLimit_rule)
```

Any advice?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(The question is quite general, so I'll propose some approaches but it's up to you to decide which ones work best in which situation.)

**EDIT 1 - sparse components**: for sparsity-related issues, see this question: [Create a variable with sparse index in pyomo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54926298/create-a-variable-with-sparse-index-in-pyomo)
Essentially, you should initialize your *sets* so that they only contain the "valid" values, and that will automatically ensure that you are only initializing the required components.

**EDIT 2 - optional components**: there are several ways to add optional components to the model. A simple `if` statement is a strategy, or you could look into [BuildActions](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/working_abstractmodels/BuildAction.html). Another option is to create `Expressions` (combinations of parameters and variables), and "optionally" change those instead of the constraint definition itself.

If all your constraints have that form (i.e. if 0 is the "neutral" state for your variables), what you can do is re-write them as:

```py
def buildLimit_rule(m):  
    return sum(m.y[n] for n in m.N) <= m.P + m.buildLimitSlack * m.useSlacks
```

If you have more than one slack variable with independent on/off parameters:

```py
def buildLimit_rule(m):  
    return sum(m.y[n] for n in m.N) <= m.P + m.v1 * m.use_v1 + m.v2 * m.use_v2 + ...
```

The most general (but less readable) approach is to index all the potential slack variables:

```py
model.SLACKS = Set(...) # set for slack variables
model.slack = Var(model.SLACKS)
model.use_slack = Param(model.SLACKS, within=Binary)

def buildLimit_rule(m):  
    return sum(m.y[n] for n in m.N) <= m.P + sum(m.slack[i] * m.use_slack[i] for i in m.SLACKS)
```

One other way is to `fix` the variables you don't need:

```py
if not m.useSlacks:
    m.Slack.fix(0)
    m.OtherSlack.fix(0)
```

Comment: Thanks.  Both of your approaches will definitely work, but if I understand Pyomo correctly it means that the slack variables will exist in memory, i.e. will be generated.   Is that correct??  We are hoping to not create the variables in the first place whatsoever.  Our overall motivation is we will have variables that will have a **huge** domain space over multiple indexes and if we don't want to use those variables we would prefer Pyomo to never create/generate the memory for them.   Any ideas?

Comment: can you clarify a couple of things: do you have a single binary parameter that tells whether _all_ the slack variables are active or not? or are there many binary parameters, each pointing to one or more slack variables?
Is there a one-to-one correspondence between constraints and slack variables, or one to many, or many-to-many?

Comment: In the case of slacks there will be a binary parameter per constraint, i.e. we can control exactly which constraints have slacks and which don't.   But fundamentally this is about more than just the slack variables.  We will have situations where data will drive whether we want a particular variable to exist or not....

Comment: ... (cont) As a simple example perhaps if there is no ArcLength[i,j] value then we assume there is no arc between (i,j) and hence we don't want to consider variable v_flow(i,j).  Our prime motivation is to only generate variables the data indicates we need, rather than having the variables generated but set to zero.  Our models can get **huge** (eg 10Gb) and when modelling in other languages like GAMS we found that only generating the variables we need drastically reduces the model size.  I am hoping to find a way to do this.

Comment: My above comment raises a point I hadn't thought to ask:  If an instance of a variable (e.g. v_flow('a','b')) never appears in any equation in Pyomo, does it still generate that variable instance and allocate memory?

Comment: yes, it's still generated anyways. The point is that you should probably not have `('a', 'b')` at all in the set if you don't plan to use it. I edited the answer to address some of your points. This is becoming quite general, you might want to break the question down into multiple questions with more practical examples.

Comment: Thanks Giorgio.  This is a change from how things work in the modeling language we are used to.  It would appear we will need to take control over the variable generation rather than relying on the language to do this for us.  Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Just a final thing: I've used Pyomo quite a bit but there might very well be better solutions than what I've come up with, so keep looking for alternatives. If you want a taste of some crazy stuff people does with Pyomo, here is an example: https://github.com/IDAES/idaes-pse/blob/master/idaes/core/process_base.py